# AJAX drop-down-select site displaying information outside of table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Drop down-select populates with the correct data, but the output is always displayed outside of the table. What is wrong with my code? Any ideas/suggestions? Thanks in advance,

---

[image]

**select.php**

```
<?php
$q = $_GET['q'];

$con = mysqli_connect('host','username','password','database');
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");

$sql="SELECT * FROM timeSheet, timeSheetUsers WHERE timeSheet.userName=timeSheetUsers.userName AND timeSheet.userName= '".$q."' ORDER BY startTime ASC";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table border ='1'>
<tr>
<th bgcolor='#F0E68C'>username</th>
<th bgcolor='#E0FFFF'>date</th>           
<th bgcolor='#F0E68C'>starTime</th>
<th bgcolor='#E0FFFF'>endTime</th>
<th bgcolor='#F0E68C'>total</th>   
</tr>";

    echo "<br />\n";
    echo "<br />\n";
    echo "<br />\n";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<br />";
                                                            //  

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<tdbgcolor='#F0E68C'>" . $row['userName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<tdbgcolor='#F0E68C'>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<tdbgcolor='#F0E68C'>" . $row['startTime'] . "</td>";
    echo "<tdbgcolor='#F0E68C'>" . $row['endTime'] . "</td>";
    echo "<tdbgcolor='#F0E68C'>" . $row['total'] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**home.php**

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
     var txtHint = document.getElementById("txtHint");
     $("#txtHint").css("display", "none");
     $("#txtHint").fadeIn('slow');
    txtHint.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","select.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
require "credentials.php";
try {
    $database = "database"; 
    $conn     = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    echo "<p>Database Connection OK.<p>";
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    $conn->setArribute(PDO::ATT_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Could not open database.";
}

echo "<form>";
echo "<select name='selStudentWorker' onChange='showUser(this.value)'>";
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT firstName, lastName, userName FROM timeSheetUsers ORDER BY firstName ASC");
if ($sql->execute(array(
    $_SESSION['userName']
))) {
    while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
        echo "<option value='".$row['userName']."' "."selected='selected'>" . $row['firstName'] . " " . $row['lastName'] . " (" . $row['userName'] . ")";
        echo "</option>";

    }
}
echo "</select>";
echo "</form>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

*Reference:* code based off of this --> http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_database.asp

Comment: I also don't see any jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your td tags:

```
<tdbgcolor='#F0E68C'>
```

Should be:

```
<td bgcolor='#F0E68C'>
```

Comment: It can affect the display of the data outside of the table anyway. Also you don't use jQuery nowhere but the selection of txtHint element which is also selected with native javascript. Please fix the issue I suggest and see if there is any change.

Comment: @thanpa yes. that fixed the issue. Data displays inside the table now. Thanks a lot. Thank you for the suggestions. Can you please explain the part where you say I don't use jQuery anymore? what can I do to fix that part?

Comment: jQuery is a framework helping you to write easier javascript. For instance all this call you make to select.php could happen in a couple of lines of code. Read this for example: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/